# Add a fragment in between ActionBar and Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

[image: This is required]

I am done with adding Action Bar and swipe able Tabs but now I want to add a fragment above the tabs which occupies good amount of screen and contains an image some text details and a spinner/drop down list as well. How can I do that?
I could not find any method for doing this. Some conflicts arise if i try to add something above the tabs.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: post your current layout please

Comment: use [Sliding tabs](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html). It can be placed wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this example and modify according to your requirement

https://github.com/AsadSoomro/SlidingTabs/